# I'm getting an NullPointer Exception when i try to put a String from an BufferedReader into a String Array

Tags: java, process, bufferedreader, iptables

I'm using the following Code

```
public void getIPTableRules(){
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/sbin/iptables", "-L");
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        int lineCount = 0;
        String zeile;
        while ((zeile =  input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(zeile);
            System.out.println(lineCount);
            line[lineCount] = zeile;
            lineCount++;
        }

        input.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CheckFirewall.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The System.out's are printed correctly.
The Variable line is set in the Class like:

```
public String line[];
```

The Exception occurs in the Line:

```
line[lineCount] = zeile;
```

So can someone please tell my what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: Where ave u initialized ur line array?

Comment: Sorry edited my initial question as is realized i didn't mention that.

Comment: Your `line` array is likely not initialized before you're using it -- I assume you declare it somewhere, but you need to make sure it's initialized as well. In the constructor for the class, or somewhere else that will guarantee execution prior to `getIPTableRules()`, you should have something like `line = new String[100];`, although you might be better served using an ArrayList or something that gives you variable length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all probability, your `String[] line` array isn't initialized like

```
String[] line = new String[100];
```

But, since you can not be sure exactly how many lines your `Process` output may have beforehand; I suggest using a `List<String>` instead which you would initialize as

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and add your `Process` output line by line to it as

```
while ((zeile =  input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(zeile);
    System.out.println(lineCount);
    lines.add(zeile); // using List#add()
    lineCount++;
}
```

Comment: The number 100 is just a cursed a number to use to define the size of an array as 2, 7 or 1928347. You want to figure out exactly how big an array you need, OR use something with a dynamic size (or alternatively handle ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exceptions).

Comment: @Izmaki Yes, I'm not a fan either :) Hence, I proposed using a `List`.

Comment: Thanks allot, couldn't think of that and it works exactly the way i want it to!

Answer (score 3):

Have you initialized your line array? It looks like you've only declared it.

You would need to do something like this:

```
public void getIPTableRules(){
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/sbin/iptables", "-L");
    line = new String[100]; // or whatever max size you want
```

Comment: In addition to this, I would like to mention that you have to carefully think about how big an array you want, OR use a collection which size is dynamic, such as `ArrayList`. If you set the `String` array size to 2, as soon as you have some kind of input with more than 2 lines, you will get a new exception thrown at you.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized your array, only defined it:

```
public String line[];
```

you need to initialize it using the proper size:

```
public String line[] = new String[SIZE];
```

SIZE is a constant integer.

Comment: You should include how to initialize it, if this is what he needs to do.